# Problems linking to SDL2 inside of Eclipse CDT on Fedora 19

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, sdl, fedora

I am having troubles linking SDL2 to a C++ application inside of Eclipse CDT Kepler on Fedora 19 64bit. Here is what I did:

- To install SDL2 I ran the line `sudo yum install SDL2-devel.i686`
- Created a new .cpp file with copy paste code just to test the environment from [here](https://github.com/crust/sdl2-examples/blob/master/createwindow.cpp)
- Add the SDL2 library to the GCC C++ Linker: `Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries -> Libraries (-l) -> add: libSDL2.so`

Then when I saved and built the program I got the fallowing error:

```
    Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
    g++  -o "SDL2 Test"  ./src/SDL2\ Test.o   -llibSDL2.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibSDL2.so
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [SDL2 Test] Error 1
```

So then I did a file system search for SDL2 and found that the libSDL2.so exists in `/usr/lib/` and `/lib/`. Shouldn't either of those be the default location for searching for libraries? What am I missing?

(If it matters, within the .cpp file itself there are no errors, all SDL commands are recognized, it is just the linker)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I am using a 64bit version of Fedora, and trying to use 32bit libraries. I assumed that because I was developing a 32bit application, that I should use 32bit libraries. But, it worked when I uninsulated the 32bit and installed the 64bit libraries.

Also, eclipse on Linux assumes that the 'lib' prefix and '.so' postfix exist, so you do not need them when you add them to the linker within eclipse (just SDL2).